# Implicit system differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I came across a system of differential equations in the form:
$\newcommand{\D}[1]{\frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}x}}$
\begin{align}
f_1(x,y,z)\D{y}+f_2(x,y,z)\D{z}&=f_3(x,y,z),\\
f_4(x,y,z)\D{y}+f_5(x,y,z)\D{z}&=f_6(x,y,z).
\end{align}

I numerically solved the system as follows. Let $\Phi$ be given by
$$
\Phi(x,y,z)=\begin{bmatrix}y'\\z'\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(x,y,z)&f_2(x,y,z)\\
f_4(x,y,z)&f_5(x,y,z)
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
f_3(x,y,z)\\
f_6(x,y,z)
\end{bmatrix},
$$

then Euler's method takes the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}_{(i+1)}=
\begin{bmatrix}
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}_{(i)}
+h~\Phi(x,y,z).
$$

I tested this approach (using RK4 instead of Euler) for simple systems (for which I can obtain analytical solutions) and it seems to work.

Other than the matrix of $\{f_1,f_2,f_4,f_5\}$ being singular, are there any other conditions for which this method fails?

Comment: Generally speaking, any numerical integration method will fail if either your problem is ill-posed (you supply the wrong number/type of boundary condition or impose it/them at the wrong place), or if it is not stable (your Euler or RK step is too large).